# Status 404 instead of 400 when testing with Superagent / Supertest / Jest

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, jestjs, supertest

**Situation**
I am building and testing a simple api with express. One of the routes is `/api/blogs/:id`, where the api should return a status 400 if the provided id is in the wrong format, and 404 if the id is not present in the database.

**Problem**
The api works fine and responds with the right status codes when making requests by browser or the REST client plugin in vsCode. But when I make requests with a malformed id via Superagent in my unit tests, the server responds with a 404, when it should be a 400.

[image: Jest error message saying it expected status 400 but got status 404]

### **Route**

```
blogsRouter.get('/:id', async (req, res, next) => {
  try {
    const { id } = req.params;
    const blog = await Blog.findById(id);
    if (blog) {
      res.status(200).json(blog);
    } else {
      res.status(404).end();
    }
  } catch (error) {
    next(error);
  }
});
```

Normally, Mongoose throws an error when running `Blog.findById(id)`, triggering `catch (error) { next(error) }`, which executes the next middleware function `errorHandler`. For some reason though, this doesn't seem to happen when testing.

### **errorHandler**

```
const errorHandler = (error, req, res, next) => {
  if (error.name === 'CastError') {
    res.status(400).json({ error: 'malformatted id' });
    return;
  } if (error.name === 'ValidationError') {
    console.log(error.message);
    res.status(400).json({ error: error.message });
    return;
  }

  next(error);
};
```

### **test**

```
test("fails with status 400 when 'id' has wrong format", async () => {
  const invalidId = '45234sdsdasf';
  await api.get(`/api/blogs/${invalidId}`)
    .expect(400);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution.

The problem was `const invalidId = '45234sdsdasf'`.

This should be a malformed id, but for some reason **Mongoose sees 12 characters long strings as a correct objectId**. Changing invalidId to something else solved the problem.